# 3 Votos para el cierre. ¿Cómo nos esta yendo?

Tags: discusión, votos-de-cierre, votos-de-reapertura

### ACTUALIZACIÓN: aunque el periodo de test a terminado, el cambio ha sido bien recibido por la comunidad así que optamos por no resetear la cantidad de votos necesarios para cerrar/reabrir a 5 mientras revisamos los datos.

Por favor, háganme saber si tienen alguna preocupación sobre este cambio en el proceso planeado o si sienten que el numero de votos debe ser cambiado a 5 por lo menos temporariamente. Volveré en algunas semanas con los resultados del proyecto.

---

### UPDATE: While the testing period has ended, this change has been well-received by the community so we have opted to not reset the votes needed to close/reopen to 5 while we look at data.

Please let me know if you have any concerns about this change in the planned process or if you feel the number of votes should be changed back at least temporarily. I'll be back in a few weeks with the results of the project.

---

Parte de entender el impacto del cierre de tres votos es comprender qué impacto está teniendo en todos ustedes. Me gustaría pedirle a cualquier persona que quiera **escribir una respuesta a esta pregunta** y que nos cuente su experiencia durante las últimas semanas.

El tipo de cosas que me interesa saber (siéntase libre de abordar todas o ninguna o agregar las suyas propias):

- ¿Esto ayudó?
- ¿No ayudó?
- ¿Hizo que te interesaras mas en cerrar / reabrir la revisión? ¿Menos?

  - ¿Hay otras cosas que no sean un cierre de 3 votos que afecten tu interés en la revisión?
- Si no puedes votar pero puedes reportar, ¿esto hizo que fuera más o menos probable que lo hicieras?
- ¿Preferirías volver a 5 votos?
- ¿Debería ser permanente?
- ¿Qué les gustaría que investigara a la hora de analizar los datos de la prueba?
- ¿Hubo efectos secundarios (buenos o malos) a los cuales debería estar atenta?

Estas son meras indicaciones, así que siéntanse libres de agregar cualquier cosa que me falte y que crean que vale la pena decir. Esto se centra en cómo se sienten al respecto y qué datos quieren que mire, así que no sientan que necesitan analizar los datos de los últimos 30 días, aunque pueden hacerlo si así es como prefieren armar la respuesta.

Si tiene alguna pregunta pendiente, no dude en hacerla aquí.

La prueba se ejecutará hasta aproximadamente el lunes 21 de junio, momento en el que restableceremos los votos para cerrar a 5 mientras reviso las respuestas aquí y profundizo en los datos que hemos estado recopilando.

(N.T: se aceptan tanto respuestas en español, las cuales traduciremos para que Catija pueda analizar sin necesidad de un traductor, como tambien en los dos lenguajes, para que quien no hable ingles pueda leerlas)

---

Part of understanding the impact of three-vote closure is to understand what impact it's having on y'all. I'd like to ask anyone who feels up to it to **write an answer to this question** and to tell us about your experience over the past few weeks.

The sorts of things I'm interested in knowing (feel free to address all or none or add your own) -

- Did this help?
- Did it hurt?
- Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing? Less?

  - Are there things other than 3-vote close impacting your interest in reviewing?
- If you can't vote but do flag, did this make you more/less likely to flag?
- Would you prefer to go back to 5?
- Should it be permanent?
- What would you like me to look into when it comes to analyzing the data from the test?
- Were there any side-effects (good or bad) that you want me to be aware of?

These are merely prompts, so feel free to add anything I'm missing that you think is worth saying. This is focused on how you're feeling about it and what data you want me to look at, so don't feel like you need to analyze the data over the last 30 days - though you're welcome to if that's how you figure out what you feel.

If you have any outstanding questions, also feel welcome to ask them here.

The test will run until about Monday the 21st of June, at which point we'll be resetting the votes to close up to 5 while I review the responses here and dig into the data that we've been collecting.

Comment: @Japv lo podes poner como respuesta asi le queda a Catija? en lo posible en los dos idiomas...

Answer (score 12):

Trataré de responder a cada pregunta:

> ¿Esto ayudó? ¿No ayudó?

Desde mi percepción, ayudó, y bastante. (¡Algunas preguntas fueron cerradas en menos de 5 minutos!)

> ¿Hizo que te interesaras más en cerrar / reabrir la revisión? ¿Menos?
> ¿Hay otras cosas que no sean un cierre de 3 votos que afecten tu interés en la revisión?

Aún no tengo acceso a la cola de votos de cierre, así que no podría opinar al respecto.

> Si no puedes votar pero puedes reportar, ¿esto hizo que fuera más o menos probable que lo hicieras?

Las probabilidades siempre son altas, pero el incentivo es mucho más alto cuando se sabe que la pregunta *se cerraría en menos tiempo de lo habitual*, por decirlo de alguna manera.

> ¿Preferirías volver a 5 votos?

No.

> ¿Debería ser permanente?

¡Por supuesto!

> ¿Qué les gustaría que investigara a la hora de analizar los datos de la prueba?

Lo único que se me ocurre (que de seguro lo harán) es comparar los tiempos de cierre de las preguntas, teniendo 5 y 3 votos de cierre.

> ¿Hubo efectos secundarios (buenos o malos) a los cuales debería estar atenta?

No se me ocurre ninguno.

---

I'll try to answer each question:

> Did this help? Did it hurt?

From my perception, it helped, and quite a lot. (Some of the questions were closed in less than 5 minutes!)

> Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing? Less? Are there things other than 3-vote close impacting your interest in reviewing?

I don't yet have access to Close votes queue, so I wouldn't be able to give my opinion on this.

> If you can't vote but do flag, did this make you more/less likely to flag?

The odds are always high, but the incentive is much higher when you know that the question *would be closed in less time than usual*, so to speak.

> Would you prefer to go back to 5?

No.

> Should it be permanent?

Of course!

> What would you like me to look into when it comes to analyzing the data from the test?

The only thing I can think of (which I'm sure you will) is to compare the closing times of the questions, having 5 and 3 close votes.

> Were there any side-effects (good or bad) that you want me to be aware of?

Nothing comes to my mind.

Answer (score 9):

#### Respuesta en español

1. ***¿Esto ayudó? ¿No ayudó?*** Concordando el primer punto con lo que dice @padaleiana, el cierre de tres votos ayudó bastante a optimizar las tareas de revisión y a cerrar eficazmente las preguntas mal formuladas.
2. ***¿Hizo que te interesaras más en las revisiones cerrar/reabrir? ¿Menos?*** Ahora me intereso más, en *publicaciones de baja calidad* específicamente, pues antes no entraba mucho al sitio, ahora intento revisar todas las preguntas que llegan a las colas de revisión.
3. ***¿Preferirías volver a 5 votos?*** En definitiva no, las preguntas mal formuladas tendrían más tiempo en el sitio, algunos usuarios que no entienden aún del todo el sitio podrían responderlas, lo cual no es el objetivo, al volver a 5 votos, tendríamos que esperar mucho más para cerrar/reabrir preguntas.
4. ***¿Debería ser permanente?*** ¡Claro!
5. ***¿Qué les gustaría que investigara a la hora de analizar los datos de la prueba?*** No se me ocurre nada.
6. ***¿Hubo efectos secundarios (buenos o malos) a los cuales debería estar atenta?*** Desde lo que he visto, ninguno.

---

#### Answer in English

1. ***Did this help? Did this hurt?*** Agreeing the first point with what @padaleiana says, the closing of three votes helped a lot to optimize the revision tasks and to effectively close the poorly formulated questions.
2. ***Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing? Less?*** Now I am more interested in *poor quality publications* specifically, because before I did not enter the site much, now I try to review all the questions that arrive in the review queues.
3. ***Would you prefer to go back to 5?*** In short, no, poorly formulated questions would have more time on the site, some users who do not yet fully understand the site could answer them, which is not the objective, when returning to 5 votes, we would have to wait much longer to close / reopen questions.
4. ***Should it be permanent?*** Yes!
5. ***What would you like me to look into when it comes to analyzing the data from the test?*** I can not think of anything.
6. ***Were there any side-effects (good or bad) that you want me to be aware of?*** From what I've seen, none.

Answer (score 7):

Mod view:

This is making our job easier. We are not asked to rush to close something that user can close by themself.

Since user has only 20 close votes, this is making easier for user not to spend all the votes needed to close. Fewer users using close votes left the user more room to close other post that has problems.

---

Punto de vista de un moderador:

Esto hace nuestro trabajo mas fácil. No se nos pide que nos apuremos a cerrar algo que los usuarios pueden cerrar por si mismos.

Como los usuarios tienen solo 20 votos de cierre, esto hace mas fácil que los usuarios no gasten todos los votos necesarios para cerrar. Menos usuarios usando votos de cierre deja espacio para que los usuarios puedan cerrar otras publicaciones con problemas.

Comment: el número de votos disponibles al día varía, yo tengo 24 por ejemplo.

Comment: no me gusta que haya un limite de votos °-°

Answer (score 4):

**Español:**

Yo veo el cambio positivo, me parece que tres votos esta bien.

**Ingles:**

I see the positive change, it seems to me that 3 votes is fine

Answer (score 2):

### ¿Esto ayudó? ¿No ayudó?

No tengo ni idea, el límite al que una pregunta debe ser considerada cerrada es arbitrario y seguramente no tenga nada que ver con el sitio si no con la pregunta. Algunas preguntas merecen ser cerradas con cero votos y otras requieren un mayor consenso y debate alrededor de su validez.

### ¿Hizo que te interesaras mas en cerrar / reabrir la revisión? ¿Menos?

Con toda sinceridad, desde que se equiparó el valor de las preguntas a las respuestas, he perdido por completo la fe en el sistema de StackOverflow y desde entonces mi participación en las tareas de revisión ha sido nula. Creo que StackOverflow da tumbos como un pollo sin cabeza y no sabe ni por dónde sopla el viento, no creo que este feedback vaya a servir de nada porque acabará haciendo lo que le venga en gana. Así que respondiendo a la pregunta: Ni más ni menos, mi interés en la revisión sigue siendo nulo.

### ¿Hay otras cosas que no sean un cierre de 3 votos que afecten tu interés en la revisión?

Pues mira, ahora que lo preguntas: si. Recuperaría mi ilusión y compromiso con StackOverflow si me diera la sensación de que escuchan a la comunidad y actúan con ella en lugar contra ella promocionando tonterías que no aportan nada a la comunidad.

### <strike>Si no puedes votar pero puedes reportar, ¿esto hizo que fuera más o menos probable que lo hicieras?</strike>

N/A.

### ¿Preferirías volver a 5 votos? ¿Debería ser permanente?

Me da bastante igual.

### ¿Qué les gustaría que investigara a la hora de analizar los datos de la prueba?

Me gustaría que se estudiase si la cantidad de votos puede ser dinámica en lugar de algo estático. No todas las preguntas de todas las etiquetas de todos los sitios de todos los usuarios merecen el mismo trato.

### ¿Hubo efectos secundarios (buenos o malos) a los cuales debería estar atenta?

Ni idea, no le he prestado mucha atención al experimento.

---

### Did this help? Did it hurt?

I don't know, where to put the limit for a question to be tagged as closed is arbitrary and might have nothing to do with the site but with the question itself. Some questions deserve to be cloesd with zero votes and others might require a greater amount of debate and consensus around their worth.

### Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing? Less?

To be completely honest, I've lost my faith on the StackOverflow network since the moment where the questions and the answers were treated with the same value. From then muy participation on the revision queues has dropped to zero. I trully believe that StackOverflow is running like a headless chicken without knowing from where the wind is blowing, I don't think that this feedback will serve any purpose at all because StackOverflow will end doing whatever it wants. So, answering the question: No more nor less, my interest on the revision queues is still zero.

### Are there things other than 3-vote close impacting your interest in reviewing?

Well, now that you mention it: yes. I'll be more invested and happy if I can feel that StackOverflow trully listens to its community and acts with it instead of promiting bull#### that doesn't enriches the community.

### <strike>If you can't vote but do flag, did this make you more/less likely to flag?</strike>

N/A.

### Would you prefer to go back to 5? Should it be permanent?

I couldn't care less.

### What would you like me to look into when it comes to analyzing the data from the test?

I would like to investigate if the close vote amount can be dynamic instead of a fixed limit. Not all the questions under all the flags for all the sites by all the users deserve the same treatement.

### Were there any side-effects (good or bad) that you want me to be aware of?

No clue, I wasn't paying any attention to this test.

Comment: Hola, no entiendo tu penúltima respuesta, la de los votos dinámicos. Por otra parte concuerdo en que una pregunta no puede tener el mismo valor que una respuesta

Comment: @Japv con votos dinámicos me refiero a que hay preguntas que tienen pocas dudas de que merecen ser cerradas, así que con 0 votos para cerrarlas sería suficiente; otras preguntas no se tiene tan claro y tal vez necesiten 3, 5 o 15 votos para ser cerradas.

Answer (score 1):

**Español:**

Como Usuario con un poco de experiencia, No he percibido diferencia o un impacto en el sitio.

Esto puede estar afectando más a usuario nuevos (que no saben que pueden dar un feedback) o los moderadores que atienden las quejas por preguntas y respuestas cerradas.

**Ingles:**

As a user with a little experience, I have not perceived a difference or an impact on the site.

This may be affecting more new users (who do not know they can give feedback) or the moderators who attend to complaints for closed questions and answers.